# Asp.net identity 2.0 password policy change no MVC

Tags: asp.net, identity, password-policy

I am recreating a project in asp.net 4.5 without MVC but using Identity 2.0.  There are no examples on the net about changing the Identity password policy without using MVC... sadly.  Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for understanding how this is done, is to create a new dummy website project by template with authentication. In Visual Studio 2013 this is done by *New Project -> Web -> ASP.NET Web Application*. In the popping up window you select *Web Forms*. There check if the authentication is set to *Single User Accounts* or something similar (I am using the german version of Visual Studio here). This should be the default setting.

***IdentityConfig.cs***

After creating the project you have a lot of sample files in your solution. Change to *App_Start -> IdentityConfig.cs*. In this class you can set the password policy in this class:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser> {
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store) {}

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager) {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser> {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser> {
            Subject = "SecurityCode",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null) {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

In this block

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator {
    RequiredLength = 6,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
    RequireDigit = true,
    RequireLowercase = true,
    RequireUppercase = true,
};
```

you can configure the password policy the way you like.

***StartUp.Auth.cs***

Afterwards have a look at the partial class Startup in *App_Start -> Startup.Auth.cs*

There you can see, how the authentication is being configured

```
public partial class Startup {
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***Startup.cs***

Last but not least check out the class *Startup.cs* which you find in the root of your dummy project, to see where the *ConfigureAuth* method is being called

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(your_dummy_project_namespace.Startup))]
namespace your_dummy_project_namespace
{
    public partial class Startup {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```